# Unable to autoload constant ApplicationController(all controllers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started receiving this error for all controller.
Not sure what happened, because I was working on UI so CSS, ERB files and then I reload the page and start getting this error.

Thanks for any advice and help.

**Controllers:** (app/controllers/...)

```
home_controller.rb
application_controller.rb
```

**In home_controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

**In application_controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}

  # HOME
  root to: 'home#index'

  # MESSENGER
  match '/webhook', :controller => 'messenger', :action => 'callback', :via => :post
  get '/webhook' => 'messenger#verify_callback'
end
```

**Error:** (for all controllers same error except constant and path)

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant HomeController, expected /home/ubuntu/line/app/controllers/home_controller.rb to define it):

activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:81:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `controller'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (20.3ms)
Started POST "/webhook" for 66.220.152.184 at 2017-02-20 04:02:49 +0000
Cannot render console from 66.220.152.184! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

LoadError (Unable to autoload constant ApplicationController, expected /home/ubuntu/line/app/controllers/application_controller.rb to define it):

app/controllers/messenger_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (22.7ms)
```

Comment: what were the changes...can you tell us ?

Comment: Just a few lines of css and html nothing what can affect whole app.. i tried to reverse changes and still get the same error

Comment: show me your routes.rb please

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using C9 and ssh for AWS server.. The problem was in C9, because it didn't sync the files well, so when I close the file and reopen it, the files were empty..

In case if someone is using C9 and will have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a routes issue. The problem is a constant resolution issue (plus autoloading) because it is saying it's not finding the `HomeController` class in `home_controller.rb`, despite the fact that it's defined there.

Try restarting the server process. Even though autoloading should handle any changes to classes, sometimes I've seen it fail. I've also seen the same issue happen with the `spring` preloader.

If this doesn't work, can you let us know whether you're using an IDE, and what happens if you try to interact with the `ApplicationController` class within the console.

Comment: Alright, I gonna try that tomorrow because I just left office.. But thanks for the explanation and details about the issue.

Comment: I tried to restart server, but i'm still getting same errors, using NGINX and RMV for rails app. Btw.. what u mean about `spring` should i try to reinstall that gem?

Comment: @LiborZahrádka I don't think it'll be a `spring` gem problem, it doesn't run in development I don't think. IDE is also probably irrelevant. Can you pop open `rails console` and try call `ApplicationController` and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah my bad i forget to tell u i also tried to interact with controller.. When i type `ApplicationController` it just disappear and if i try to `def test` in it and then `ApplicationController.new.test` it return me the same error Unable to autoload constant

Comment: Huh. What happens if you try `require 'app/controllers/application_controller'` in console first?

Comment: I finally found the problem.. im using C9 and ssh with AWS server.. The problem was there because C9 somehow didnt sync the files well and when i close them and reopen, 4 files were empty.. included home_controller what was causing the problem.. But I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Fascinating! I guess it was all about the IDE after all :)

Comment: Yeah not sure what happend but all files what i was editing were empty included that controller, applications.scss, js and erb file.. 2 days stuck with that and all i had to do is just reopen the files.. that kind of funny

Comment: @LiborZahrádka now we know :) You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that all your controllers are giving this error please check in file `application.rb` and add this line or a similar to below

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/controllers)
```

The above may be because of some change in your `application.rb` your getting this error which is preventing it from auto loading all your controllers

Comment: I tried that in `application.rb` but nothing change

Comment: @Umar, This wouldn't have helped; it was attempting to autoload from the correct path. I believe not including an `autoload_path` generates the standard undefined constant error.